# How to setup a ListView to reflect an SQLiteDatabase using a cursor (will need code example)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor

**I will need a code example; I'm not very experienced.**

I need a ListView to reflect an SQLiteDatabase using a cursor. Here's my main.java:

```
package com.shoppinglist;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ShoppingList extends ListActivity {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button1main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        button1main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)  {
            final Dialog additem = new Dialog(ShoppingList.this);
            additem.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
            final EditText et = (EditText)additem.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
            additem.setTitle("Type your item");
            additem.setCancelable(true);
            et.setHint("Type the name of an item...");

            Button button = (Button) additem.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)  {
                    additem.dismiss();
                }
            });
            additem.show();

            Button ok = (Button) additem.findViewById(R.id.ok);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final String text = et.getText().toString();
                    additem.dismiss();
                    et.setText("");
                }
            });
       }
        });
    }
}
```

My DataHelper.java:

```
package com.shoppinglist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "items.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";

    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
    private static final String INSERT = "insert into "
        + TABLE_NAME + "(name) values (?)";

    public DataHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
        this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
        }

        public long insert(String name) {
            this.insertStmt.bindString(1, name);
            return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
        }

        public void deleteAll() {
            this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
        }

        public List<String> selectAll() {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "name" },
                    null, null, null, null, "name desc");
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    list.add(cursor.getString(0));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            if (cursor !=null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            return list;
        }

        private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            OpenHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            @Override
              public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");
              }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                Log.w("Example", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
                onCreate(db);
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void doInsert(String name) {
                final SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
                SQLiteStatement insert_stmt = null;
                try {
                    insert_stmt = db.compileStatement(INSERT);
                    insert_stmt.bindString(0, name);
                    insert_stmt.executeInsert();
                }
                finally {
                    if (insert_stmt !=null) insert_stmt.close();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a cursor data adapter to fill the data. The [developer's site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html) has something you should start with.

Moreover, my [Android-Binding](http://code.google.com/p/android-binding/wiki/BindingListOfObjects) supports such kind of mapping, without explicitly implementing an adapter.

Comment: What should the textArrayResId be?

Comment: Look at the Simple Cursor Adapter section, or you might take a look at the Notepad tutorial

Comment: Maybe you should start with this before going back to your own. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Comment: I did, LOL, but I'll try it again

Comment: I keep getting an error at Cursor c = db.query("TABLE_NAME", and I think it's the TABLE_NAME thing.

Comment: db.query(TABLE_NAME,...) TABLE_NAME is a variable in your above example given. And make sure you DID opened the database before query, and keep the db open until you finished with the cursor.

Comment: Here's the only problem, I somehow can't do getWritableDatabase(). It says The method getWritableDatabase() is undefined for the type DataHelper.